# Organizing a "speedback"

Tags: combinatorics, functional-programming

[Speedback is the merging of speed-dating with feedback: a 2 min. 1-on-1 talk with all members of a group of people.](https://medium.com/@joshdesign/speedback-de-stigmatise-feedback-with-speed-dating-principles-4708d493fb63)

I'm in a team and I want to plan the ideal speedback setup: all team members have to give feedback to eachother.
I want to group people in a way that maximizes the concurrency of simultaneous pairs so we reduce the total time of the sessions.

Consider the input:
"alexandre", "sergiu", "joana", "tiago", "susana", "david"

combinations(6,2) = 15 possible pairs

1st session:

```
"alexandre" with "sergiu"
"joana" with "tiago"
"susana" with "david"
```

2nd session:

```
"alexandre" with "joana"
"sergiu" with "tiago"
"joana" with "david"
```

3rd session:

...

you get the ideia.. until everyone "dates" everyone.

I need all the possible pairs to be matched in the end.

Do you how to get this output? (or can you hint about the solution)?

Comment: Kotlin-specific questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Moreover, I don't understand what you're looking for. What is the input, and what is the required output?

Comment: Also, note that if you're interested in heterosexual dating, then you probability want to take the Cartesian product of the set of men with the set of women, rather than what you're doing.

Comment: forget Kotlin. you can reply in pseudocode 
I'll give an input and output in the example in a while :)
heterosexual?! I did not get the question. all have to give feedback to all. there's no sex related question

Comment: Your current code considers all pairs of people out of both men and women at the same time. This means that you're also considering homosexual pairs. I have absolutely no problem with that, but I suspect that it's not what you intended.

Comment: here the sex is irrelevant. we work in a team and everyone has to give feedback to everyone. I wanted to give a real problem behind to make it more easy to explain maybe I failed. I edited to make it more clear

Comment: I could have said A, B, C, D and F but I decided to give my real problem.

Comment: The term "dating" has very specific connotations in English.

Comment: you're right. it was ambiguous

Comment: better explanation here https://medium.com/@joshdesign/speedback-de-stigmatise-feedback-with-speed-dating-principles-4708d493fb63
you can scroll to the end to the images

Comment: The general problem you're describing here seems to be finding a schedule for a round-robin tournament. There are many ways to construct such a schedule, some of them listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm). However, the link you give already describes a way to get a round-robin schedule, known as the "circle method". Do you want to find a different method? Or is there something you want to know about the method given in the link?

Comment: initially I wanted to know the functional programming approach but then I realized maybe this is not the place to ask. So I decided to still leave the question to learn more about the theory behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that your team contains $n$ people. Each round of discussions ("session") corresponds to a matching in the complete graph $K_n$. Therefore you want to partition into as few matchings as possible. The answer depends on the parity of $n$.

**Case 1: $n$ is even.** In this case, $K_n$ contains $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, and a matching contains at most $n/2$ edges. Hence we can hope for a partition of $K_n$ into $n-1$ perfect matchings. This is a standard problem, known as *1-factorization of the complete graph*. Here is one solution:
$$
(0,n-1),(1,n-2),(2,n-3),(3,n-4),\ldots,(n/2-1,n/2) \\
(1,n-1),(2,0),(3,n-2),(4,n-3),\ldots,(n/2,n/2+1) \\
(2,n-1),(3,1),(4,0),(5,n-2),\ldots,(n/2+1,n/2+2) \\
\ldots
$$
Explanation: the $i$'th row consists of $(i,n-1)$ together with $(j+i,n-1-j+i \bmod n-1)$ for $1 \leq j \leq n/2-1$. For example, when $n = 6$ you get:
$$
(0,5),(1,4),(2,3) \\
(1,5),(2,0),(3,4) \\
(2,5),(3,1),(4,0) \\
(3,5),(4,2),(0,1) \\
(4,5),(0,3),(1,2)
$$

**Case 2: $n$ is odd.** In this case, $K_n$ still contains $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, but now each matching contains at most $(n-1)/2$ edges. Hence we can hope for a partition of $K_n$ into $n$ almost-perfect matchings. We can take the solution above for $n+1$, and just ignore the match of vertex $n$. This gives the following solution:
$$
(1,n-1),(2,n-2),(3,n-3),\ldots,((n-1)/2,(n+1)/2) \\
(2,0),(3,n-1),(4,n-2),\ldots,((n+1)/2,(n+3)/2) \\
(3,1),(4,0),(5,n-1),\ldots,((n+3)/2,(n+5)/2) \\
\ldots
$$
Explanation: the $i$th row consists of $(j+i,n-j+i \bmod n)$ for $1 \leq j \leq (n-1)/2$. For example, when $n = 7$ you get:
$$
(1,6),(2,5),(3,4) \\
(2,0),(3,6),(4,5) \\
(3,1),(4,0),(5,6) \\
(4,2),(5,1),(6,0) \\
(5,3),(6,2),(0,1) \\
(6,4),(0,3),(1,2) \\
(0,5),(1,4),(2,3)
$$

Comment: this is awesome. thank you very much! now I'll try to implement it :D

Comment: I must be doing something wrong https://pl.kotl.in/HG9uJ5cjX
For the n=6, I copied the formula but I get different results. I will try in paper to see what I missed. Is it some parentheses missing?

Comment: are parentheses missing for the mod? I added them
https://pl.kotl.in/HtwQIUgl0
still not perfect but close

Comment: For me the precedence of mod is lowest, which is equivalent to adding parenthesis to the entire expression on left and right. However, even better is to try to figure out the formula from the examples.

Comment: For the even case, I think you meant *j + 1 mod n - 1* (and mod n for the odd case)